# How do I get the node value using xpath and php here?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

The below code is supposed to print: PHP XPath Example, but it doesn't. I'm not sure why.

***articles.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
    <article id="1">
        <tags>
            <tag>php</tag>
            <tag>xpath</tag>
        </tags>
        <title>PHP XPath Example</title>
    </article>
    <article id="2">
        <tags>
            <tag>dom</tag>
            <tag>dodocument</tag>
        </tags>
        <title>DomDocument Tutorial</title>
    </article>
</articles>
```

***test.php:***

```
<?php
require 'krumo/class.krumo.php';
//phpinfo();
$file = "/home/veronzhg/public_html/venturelateral.com/pi_candidate_project/articles.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
krumo($xml);
$arts = $xml->xpath("/articles/article/title");

krumo($arts);
foreach ($arts as $art)
{
    echo $art->textContent ." printed <br />";
    //nodeValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
$stringxml = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<articles>
    <article id="1">
        <tags>
            <tag>php</tag>
            <tag>xpath</tag>
        </tags>
        <title>PHP XPath Example</title>
    </article>
    <article id="2">
        <tags>
            <tag>dom</tag>
            <tag>dodocument</tag>
        </tags>
        <title>DomDocument Tutorial</title>
    </article>
</articles>

EOD;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($stringxml);

foreach ($xml->xpath('/articles/article/title') as $title)
{
    echo "$title\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize that the value in the foreach wasn't an object.